# Device tree debugging

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, device-tree

I have a very basic question about the Linux Device Tre
I'm trying to build a device tree coming from an existing project, the device tree compiler just refuses like this:

```
Error: fsl-imx8mq-var-dart-common.dtsi:722.18-19 syntax error
FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree
```

It's quite clear that I'm stumbling into some kind of syntax error, but I'm puzzled by the numbers reported, i expected 722 to be the line number, but it seems not the case.

What is the meaning of those number? I could not find a way to make dtc more verbose.

<s>(I'm not adding the device tree yet since it's 2000 lines)</s>

Thanks in advance

EDIT: the dt is here
[https://pastebin.com/dWF8fV32[][1]](https://pastebin.com/dWF8fV32%5B%5D%5B1%5D)

Comment: Yes, its line number.  Are your line endings correct?

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/50658326/1216776

Comment: Thanks, i tested it by adding some errors on other lines, but i probably misjudged the results... Is there any way to make the output more verbose? Or any other tool that can help me in the debugging beside dtc?

Comment: Post the block of lines leading up to 722.  Make sure you cut and paste, not retype.

Comment: Forget about it... i tough the "#" were comments and the stripped device tree is missing a lot of stuff... I think my question makes a lot less sense now, thanks for your time