# Final State of DTS After Preprocessing

Tags: c, preprocessor, device-tree

In short, what is the final textual state of a valid DTS file after it has been run through the C preprocessor?  Exactly what should be left behind from `#include` directives?  How much of this is `dtc` supposed to tolerate?  Did the Linux headers have to be specially laid out to support inclusion in a DTS file?

---

For fun and profit, I am adding device tree support to a FreeRTOS project.  In doing so, I need to add build support to actually generate and embed my DTB into the final binary.  The first step is to run the preprocessor on the DTS to convert C definitions.  This preprocessed DTS is then fed to `dtc` to create the final DTB.

I have all of the build integration and such working but I am getting tripped up by the preprocess step.  I have seen numerous posts online which all are a variation on the arguments specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658326/device-tree-compiler-not-recognizes-c-syntax-for-include-files); my specific incantation (I am using CMake currently) is:

```
"${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}" "-D$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:${COMPONENT_LIB},COMPILE_DEFINITIONS>,$<SEMICOLON>-D>"
                      "-I$<JOIN:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:${COMPONENT_LIB},INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>,$<SEMICOLON>-I>"
                       -E -P --undef __ASSEMBLER__ -x assembler-with-cpp -o "${CURRENT_DTS_PREPROCESS}" "${CURRENT_DTS}"
```

This command completes successfully but the subsequent `dtc` step fails to parse the preprocessed DTS with syntax errors.  If I examine these errors, they are all on C declarations that would survive the proprocessor.  For example, here are the first couple of lines of the preprocessed output:

```
/dts-v1/;


typedef signed char __int8_t;
typedef unsigned char __uint8_t;
typedef short int __int16_t;
typedef short unsigned int __uint16_t;
typedef int __int32_t;
typedef unsigned int __uint32_t;
typedef long long int __int64_t;
...
```

Presumably the first include file to be considered is `stdint.h` or similar, hence the definitions for all of the fixed-width types first.  The first syntax error reported by `dtc` is `/path/to/dts.preprocess:4.1-8 syntax error` which exactly corresponds to the first `typedef` token (with trailing space).

So, should the device tree compiler be tolerant of this or am I missing something in my incantation to elide all C definitions that aren't `#define` substitutions?  Or is there something else at work here?

Comment: I don't know what's happening in your case, but the C preprocessor is not specified to process headers other than those that are *explicitly* referenced by `#include` directives.

Comment: @JohnBollinger To be clear, I do have an include directive at the top of my DTS which pulls in all of the above.  Based on the discussion on [LKML](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/51157F65.2050309@wwwdotorg.org/T/#m2c87ecd501b3240fd996cf1be1b8852e979df25a), I have a suspicion that Linux had to manually cook their headers to not conflict with DTS syntax.  Waiting to post this result as an answer, however, in case somebody knows more or a functional workaround.

Comment: I have no personal experience with DeviceTree, but none of the documentation or examples I've been looking at suggest that it is conventional or appropriate for DeviceTree sources to `#include` C library header files.  Your LKML link does not suggest otherwise to me.  The ability to use `#include` in a DTS file does not imply that it is appropriate to apply that ability to C header files. YMMV.

Comment: "*what is the final textual state of a valid DTS file after it has been run through the C preprocessor?*" -The last time I looked at the preprocessor output of a (ARM Linux kernel) **.dts** file (which was probably a decade ago), there where no typedef or C statements. The output was all DT statements but with numeric values instead of some symbols (and a lot of added blank lines).

Comment: In the Linux kernel DT source, I've only seen files included that were in the **dts/** subdirectory (i.e. **.dtsi** files) or from **include/dt-bindings/**. So there was no possibility of C statements in a DT file.

Answer (score 0):

Per [discussion on the Linux Kernel Mailing List](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/51157F65.2050309@wwwdotorg.org/T/#m2c87ecd501b3240fd996cf1be1b8852e979df25a) as well as @JohnBollinger's and @sawdust's comment, it looks like the Linux headers had to be specifically laid out to support inclusion into a device tree.  Specifically, they were intentionally set up to not contain C directives which are not valid DTS syntax.  Bummer.

Near as I can tell, the only way to do this without duplicating / reworking headers would be ANOTHER process step after the C preprocessor but before `dtc` invocation to strip out the leftover C gunk.  This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: "*Near as I can tell, the only way to do this ...*" - Maybe not. The beginning of that LKML discussion mentions that this header issue can also affect an assembly language file. There's mention of a macro `__ASSEMBLY__ ` and a command line option `-x assembler-with-cpp`. Supposedly there's a (proposed?)  `__DTS__` macro that is also set, that "*allow header files to restrict their content to that compatible with device tree source.*"

Comment: @sawdust: That is a much better option, IMO, if you can control the entire source tree.  In my case I cannot edit the upstream headers which provide the defines I want, which is why the next part of the sentence you quote is *"...without duplicating / **reworking** headers..."*.  ;-P